# nested ListView not getting values from parent listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

My site is in c# & is fully dynamic. The Menu bar is also dynamic. Each navigation menu has sub menus.. Because Menus needs to be build from database I have used Listview Control. In my website for menus I need to use 2 child Listview inside one parent Listview. So it look like this.

Parent Menu Listview has Sub menu listview & sub Menu listviews has another child Listview in which I need to show any one product related parent Listview Category..

My Sub Menu has builded properly but inside that If I tries to bind another Listview then it shows me the error (Object reference not set as an instance of an object.) Then I tried with manual sql query without getting where clause from ItemDataBound defined then too it shows same error.

How my menus looks like (the empty space(right side) in sub menu where I want to display one product of power bank category)
[image]

```
<asp:ListView ID="mainMenu" runat="server" DataKeyNames="name" OnItemDataBound="OnItemDataBound">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <li><asp:HyperLink ID="mainLinks" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("name", "~/{0}") %>' Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:HyperLink>

              <ul class="super-child">
                  <asp:ListView ID="childMenu" runat="server" DataKeyNames="name">
                       <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="super-child-inner">
                                 <div class="list-child">
                                 <li><asp:HyperLink ID="cat3" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("category") & Eval("name", "/{0}") %>' Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:HyperLink></li>
                            </div>

                            <div class="recommended">
                            <asp:ListView ID="recommendedProducts" runat="server">
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                     <div class="rec-img">
                                          <asp:Image ID="recImg" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image") %>' />
                                     </div>
                                     <p class="rec-name"><asp:HyperLink ID="recLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("category") & Eval("name", "/{0}") %>' Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:HyperLink></p>
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                              </asp:ListView>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:ListView>
           </ul>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

ItemDataBound Code

```
protected void onItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem) {
        ListViewDataItem itm = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
        string name = mainMenu.DataKeys(itm.DataItemIndex)("name");
        ListView childMenu = e.Item.FindControl("childMenu") as ListView;
        ListView recommendedProducts = e.Item.FindControl("recommendedProducts") as ListView;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr)) {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand()) {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM product_categories WHERE category = '" + name + "' and status = 'active'";
                cmd.Connection = con;
                using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)) {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    childMenu.DataSource = dt;
                    childMenu.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            string constr2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString;
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr2)) {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand()) {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID,slug,product_name,image FROM products WHERE (category Like @category) and status = 'active' Limit 1";
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoty", "%" + name + "%");
                    using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)) {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        recommendedProducts.DataSource = dt;
                        recommendedProducts.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Response.Write(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE (Exception)

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at MasterPage.onItemDataBound(Object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e) in E:\MY WEB\brandstik.com1\MasterPage.master.vb:line 79System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at MasterPage.onItemDataBound(Object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e) in E:\MY WEB\brandstik.com1\MasterPage.master.vb:line 79System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at MasterPage.onItemDataBound(Object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e) in E:\MY WEB\brandstik.com1\MasterPage.master.vb:line 79System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at MasterPage.onItemDataBound(Object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e) in E:\MY WEB\brandstik.com1\MasterPage.master.vb:line 79System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at MasterPage.onItemDataBound(Object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e) in E:\MY WEB\brandstik.com1\MasterPage.master.vb:line 79System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at MasterPage.onItemDataBound(Object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e) in E:\MY WEB\brandstik.com1\MasterPage.master.vb:line 79System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at MasterPage.onItemDataBound(Object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e) in E:\MY WEB\brandstik.com1\MasterPage.master.vb:line 79System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at MasterPage.onItemDataBound(Object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e) in E:\MY WEB\brandstik.com1\MasterPage.master.vb:line 79System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at MasterPage.onItemDataBound(Object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e) in E:\MY WEB\brandstik.com1\MasterPage.master.vb:line 79System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at MasterPage.onItemDataBound(Object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e) in E:\MY WEB\brandstik.com1\MasterPage.master.vb:line 79

Comment: I think there is a problem with the names -  In your DOM `ListView` ID is = `recommendedProduct` but you are trying to bind data to a `ListView recommendedProducts` So check it first.

Comment: @codelahiru Ys you were right I made mistake there but I changed it with correct name but problem remains the same

Comment: Do you have any exception other than `Object reference not set as an instance of an object.` ? this means you didn't create any new object from the instance before you binding the data to that instance.

Comment: @codelahiru I Posted entire exception in my post. please have a look..

Comment: @codelahiru Do you find any error with my code?

Comment: i'm just trying your code. let me get back to you soon.

Comment: @codelahiru Ok. I am just trying to build my sub menus like this http://www.amsterdamprinting.com/

Comment: why don't you step into debugger, you will see exact point (and reason) of your exception...

Comment: Which line in your question code equals line 79 in your sources?

Comment: @grek40 recommendedProducts.DataSource = dt;

Comment: @kostbone I tired to debug before posting it but still not getting the issue.

Comment: @codelahiru are you still trying? Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main concepts to be understood in order to solve the problem.

- Scope of ID values
- Timing of initialization

Regarding the scope of ID values:

The ID of an element within the `ItemTemplate` will only be available within the scope of this item. Otherwise, multiple items would produce elements with a duplicate ID value. With two items in childMenu, which one would you expect to be returned by `FindControl`?

Regarding the timing, the nested items of a `ListView` will only be created, after the `DataSource` is assigned while `DataBind` is executed. This means, you can't expect `recommendedProducts` to exist before `childMenu.DataSource = dt; childMenu.DataBind();` was executed.

In the following example, your sophisticated data logic is replaced by simple but effective debugging values:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mainMenu.DataSource = new[] { "M1", "M2" };
    mainMenu.DataBind();
}

protected void mainMenu_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    var childMenu = e.Item.FindControl("childMenu") as ListView;

    // will always be null, because ID scope is not correct
    ListView recommendedProducts1 = e.Item.FindControl("recommendedProducts") as ListView;

    // query the correct ID scope, but Items will be empty
    foreach (var item in childMenu.Items)
    {
        var recommendedProducts2 = item.FindControl("recommendedProducts") as ListView;
    }

    // initialize sub-items
    childMenu.DataSource = new object[] { "C1", "C2" };
    childMenu.DataBind();

    // query the correct ID scope, with items
    foreach (var item in childMenu.Items)
    {
        // finally, recommendedProducts for each childmenu-item within the currently processed childmenu is accessible
        var recommendedProducts3 = item.FindControl("recommendedProducts") as ListView;
        recommendedProducts3.DataSource = new[] { "Best" };
        recommendedProducts3.DataBind();
    }
}
```

My testing ASPX for completeness sake:

```
<asp:ListView ID="mainMenu" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="mainMenu_ItemDataBound">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul>
            <li id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"/>
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li runat="server">
            <%# Container.DataItem %>
            <asp:ListView ID="childMenu" runat="server">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"/>
                    </ul>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li runat="server">
                        <%# Container.DataItem %>
                        <div class="recommended">
                            <asp:ListView ID="recommendedProducts" runat="server">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div style="background-color:green">
                                        <%# Container.DataItem %>
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:ListView>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Hope this helps to understand, when and how you can access your controls.

Comment: @SUN now I am curious... was this a problem of your code or a problem of the question? If it was a problem of code: you said in comments that you already debugged the code - it should be obvious that `recommendedProducts` was null. What is it now?

Comment: In my Update it's exactly same error after changing ListView name from code but I don't understand why error still remains same..

Comment: It might also be a problem of initialization, because `recommendedProducts` is a subitem of `childMenu` and childMenu is empty at time of code execution (you fill it in the method, after you query `recommendedProducts`). Try to query `ListView recommendedProducts = childMenu.FindControl("recommendedProducts") as ListView` AFTER childMenu is initialized with datasource

Comment: @SUN edited, should now be enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Although this technique might be good but can we also do it without including third child listview & can include third child content in second child listview & to bind second listview if we can structure mysql query to connect with both tables i.e. products & Categories

Comment: @SUN maybe you can rephrase your comment, I don't fully understand what you mean. Of course you can restructure your hierarchy (and that's probably what you should do) but is that related to the question ("nested ListView not getting values from parent listview")?

Comment: What exactly I mean is if I don't implement third Listview & by using sql inner join query too connect products table & category table. I want to post this separately but not sure will it be reachable to you or not